# Integrating PartCover.NET with NAnt

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I'm trying to integrate PartCover.NET with NAnt and CruiseControl.NET
I can run PartCover.NET browser without problems, but it does not work once I try to run it in an NAnt task (in my CCNET build).

There must be an issue with my NAnt target but I can't find it. Maybe someone had experienced the same issues in the past?.

```
    <target name="CoverageUnitTest" description="Code coverage of unit tests">
    <exec program="${PartCover.exe}">
        <arg value="--target=${NUnit.console}" />
        <arg value="--target-work-dir=${project.dir}\bin\${configuration}"/>
        <arg value="--target-args=${project}.dll" />
        <arg value="--output=C:\partcover.xml" />
        <arg value="--include=[*]*" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

In CruiseControl, I got the following error message:
[exec] Invalid option '--target C:\NUnit\bin\nunit-console.exe'

```
Build Error: NAnt.Core.BuildException
External Program Failed: C:\PartCover\PartCover.exe (return code was -1)
in C:\default.build line: 20 col: 4

   at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExternalProgramBase.ExecuteTask()
   at NAnt.Core.Tasks.ExecTask.ExecuteTask()
   at NAnt.Core.Task.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Target.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute(String targetName, Boolean forceDependencies)
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Run()
```

thanks !
David

Comment: I found the answers on how to integrate it thanks to the following blog post.
http://blog.dynamicprogrammer.com/CategoryView,category,ContinuousIntegration.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace = with space and use the &quot ; marker around the parameters for the arguments

Comment: how you have solved this issue.. i am getting this error. I have tried using the above. but i am getting the error Cannot find target (nunit-console.exe). I have added the configuration in the NANT like this <arg value="--target &quot;nunit-console.exe&quot;" />

Comment: Make sure that you have location of nunit-console.exe set in the path on the machine you run the script on.

Answer (score 5):

As You may have noticed this task is rather complicated. It drove me to the edge of insanity but at last I got it running.

Here is some general advice:

- use PartCover version 2.2 instead of 2.3 since the latter is a dev version that seems to be unstable.
- remember to register PartCover.CorDriver.dll.
- passing arguments is the hardest part if You need to quote paths. I finally decided to use a configuration file and pass it via `--settings`.

Comment: (+1) Register is a fundamental point, the error don't give no one clue about.